# C# event delegate for property changed, then get value and class name to pass through socket and get on other side

Tags: c#, events, properties, delegates, synchronization

I am writing a number of classes, that I want to sync properties with over a socket. The networking code is pretty much written and I am down to the best way to sync these over the network.

I have a normal property and event setup

```
public class TestScript {

    private bool test;
    public bool Test {
        get {
            return test;
        }

        set {
            if(value != test) {
                test = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("test");
            }
        }
    }


    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

And the listener is so far setup like

```
public class TestClass {

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object obj, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

        Console.WriteLine(" hello " + e.PropertyName);
    }

}
```

Now, the output is displayed with the properties name that has changed. What I don't know how to go about is, saying what the name of the class and the actual new value is.

Then on the other side when the packet is received, I would like to take this value and store it back into the class.

Anyone able to shed some light on what I might need to read up on, maybe even provide an example of what I need to do.

**Edit:**

To be clear, I have the socket part working, sending and receiving. I just need the sync of the property change.